# remove the letter-spacing for last letter while entering 4 digit pin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Run the snippet and type letters in input pin field.

I used the css property `letter-spacing` in input field. It's creating additional space after each character.

**However, I don't want to add space after last character.** How can I achieve that?

```css
.spc {
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

#ps:nth-letter(odd) {
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

```html
PIN: <input id="ps" class="spc" type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" size="4">
```

[sample url](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G41VM01QPBJN)

Comment: if i understand you want pin: 8 8 88 ?

Comment: No, I guess he wants "8 8 8 8" instead of "8 8 8 8 "

Comment: pin like '8 8 8 8'. but with above code i am getting '8 8 8 8 '

Comment: There is no extra space in your example. The input field only allows to type 4 characters. It displays `8 8 8 8 ` with what _seems_ to be a space at the end, but it's not. It's only because the letter spacing is set to 0.2em, so characters are very wide.

Comment: `:nth-letter` is not really a thing in current CSS as far as I’m aware.

Comment: @JeremyThille That is exactly what OP is trying to solve. They want to apply additional `letter-spacing` to all letters *but the last*.

Comment: Like this? -- https://jsfiddle.net/u3hkdvgs/3/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett That just showcases the same problem on an external site, how is that supposed to help?

Comment: How is that the same problem? There is no longer space in the input box after 4 numbers are input.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Make the width bigger, and yes there is https://jsfiddle.net/rvb5ekda/

Comment: @connexo if it is no space in last char cursor going last letter with some space

Comment: I don't think it's possible without JavaScript honestly.

Comment: @JackBashford okay fine.. how to achive it using javascript

Comment: looking at the duplicates, don't think this is possible

Comment: @Abinaya - I am stuck at same issue. Did you managed to resolve it? Pls update if any